# Rewrite/transform url param to body parameter using nginx or HAProxy

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I need to transform request like this

`http://www.example.com/routeName/id123456789`

to

`http://myurl/routeName` with json payload 
`{id: id123456789}`

Is it possible using nginx or hproxy?

Thank you

Comment: Might be possible with HAProxy using embedded Lua... but this seems like a slightly unusual requirement, and I suspect more information is needed in order to fully understand what you need.  Are you also changing the request from `GET` to `POST`?  If not, is this initially a `POST` with an empty body?  Would rewriting the parameter in the query string either raw or in urlescaped JSON not suffice?  Also, are you sure you're not in [XY](http://xyproblem.info) territory here?